# SignalR: Chat between 2 identical database codes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an operator table as follows:
id, code, name

And I have a table for the logged in user:
id, code, userid

I want the same chat codes to see each other.
in my chathub:

```
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
```

and in my view:

```
 $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                $('#discussion').append('<li style="background-color: #dfdfed;margin-bottom:2px;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
                var scr = $('#uDIV')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('#uDIV').animate({ scrollTop: scr });
            };
            $('#message').focus();
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
```